# How to set default values for IPython widgets?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using IPython widgets to create an interactive plot that will help students understand the determinants of accuracy of various ODE solvers available in `scipy.integrate.ode`. However, I can't seem to find much in the way of documentation on the various types of widgets and their keyword args.

```
from IPython.html.widgets import *    

@interact(h=FloatTextWidget(), atol=FloatTextWidget(), rtol=FloatTextWidget(),
          k=IndexSliderWidget(), integrator=TextWidget()))
def plot_lotka_volterra_residuals(h=1e-1, atol=1e-3, rtol=1e-3, k=3, integrator='dopri5'):
    """Plots residuals of the Lotka-Volterra system."""
    # make a pretty plot!
```

In particular, I would like to know how to set a default value for each widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of the widgets takes a `value` keyword argument; you may be able to adapt examples [such as this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/IanHawke/findhorizon/blob/master/Black%20Hole%20Interaction.ipynb), or try [Rossant's detailed Europy tutorial](https://github.com/rossant/euroscipy2014).

Answer (score 0):

Using `ipywidgets`, an instance of a control class can be passed to interact.

```py
from ipywidgets import interact, FloatSlider

def update(a):
    print a

interact(update, a=FloatSlider(min=1000., max=100000., step=1000, value=R10, description='Parameter A'))
```

The GitHub repo has many great [examples](http://ipywidgets/docs/source/examples/Using%20Interact.ipynb).

Comment: GitHub link is dead